# Java : Memory Game

Tags: java, swing, interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I am currently working on a memory game project, where you click on two cards to check if the pictures are the same or not. The problem that I am facing is that if both cards don't have the same picture, the second picture does not appear and the first one closes as well.

Here is the code which I think has some sort of an error in.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)         
    {                    
                        clicks +=1; 
                Card clicked = (Card)e.getSource(); 
                clicked.changeColor();

                for(int i=0;i<16;i++) 
                    if(clicked == cards.get(i)) 
                        openCardIndices.add(i); 


                 if(clicks==2 && openCardIndices.get(openCardIndices.size()-1)!=openCardIndices.get(openCardIndices.size()-2)) 
                 {
                    if(cards.get(openCardIndices.get(openCardIndices.size()-1)).equals(cards.get(openCardIndices.get(openCardIndices.size()-2))))
                    {
                        (cards.get(openCardIndices.get(openCardIndices.size()-1))).removeActionListener(this);
                        (cards.get(openCardIndices.get(openCardIndices.size()-2))).removeActionListener(this);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        openCardIndices.remove(openCardIndices.size()-1);
                        openCardIndices.remove(openCardIndices.size()-1);
                        //lockCards();
                        unlockCards();
                    }
                    clicks = 0;
                 }
```

Comment: So you're just going to dump all your code on us and say "Fix it"? That's not how Stack Overflow works. We aren't your personal code debuggers - you actually have to try something!

Comment: Posting all of the code is fine I guess, but give us a detailed explanation of it, where specifically you think the problem might be originating, and in general any information that might be pertinent.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean that, and I am working on that mistake since 2-3 hours, and tried various ways but still couldn't overcome it, so I thought posting my whole code might me good if anyone wanted to try running it to see the error themselves :s I just tried commenting the unlockCards() and the second card showed, but shouldn't the program execute in order anyway, why does calling this method stop the image from showing, even if I use Thread.sleep before it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tells it to do that.

You probably want that `else` clause to do something like:

- Delay 2 seconds before hiding the cards with unlock.

or maybe

- Leave the cards alone until you click on one of them again. This would require the counter going from 1 to 2 and then to 3, where you turn them back over.

Not gonna write the code for you but its a clue.